# Xceed splitbutton with menu items and sub menuitems

Tags: wpf, drop-down-menu, menuitem, submenu, split-button

I`m trying to have a dropdown menu under a split button. Some of these menuItems should have sub-menu items. If you want an example, click on the bookmark button in Firefox (top right).

I can't use Menu, because that is always oriented horizontally. So I went with a stackpanel:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>


    <xctk:SplitButton Content="SplitButton" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0,0,408,290">
        <xctk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
            <StackPanel Width="161" HorizontalAlignment="Left">


                <MenuItem Header="MenuItem1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="517">
                    <MenuItem.Items>
                        <MenuItem Header="submenuItem1"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="submenuItem2"/>                            
                    </MenuItem.Items>

                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="MenuItem2"/>
                <MenuItem Header="MenuItem3"/>

            </StackPanel>                   
        </xctk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>

    </xctk:SplitButton>
</Grid>
```

Problem here is that the sub menu items don't show up. They don't even have the little arrows next to them. You can do this without the SplitButton, just leaving the stackpanel and everything in it, you'll have the same problem. I've tried putting the parent Menu item in its own  tag, but I want the sub-menu items to appear to the right of their parent (just like the firefox example: Assuming your firefox window is not maximized, and you've allowed enough screen-space for the item to appear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way you're using the `MenuItem` control is wrong, it is meant to be hosted inside the `Menu` control or another `MenuItem`.

As for the solution to your problem, there are two. the first one is to write a custom control that reuses the `ContextMenu` to host the menu items, you will write something like this:

```
    <m:SplitButton Content="Split Button" Placement="Bottom">
        <MenuItem Header="MenuItem 1"/> 
        <MenuItem Header="MenuItem 2"> 
             <MenuItem Header="MenuItem 1"/> 
             <MenuItem Header="MenuItem 2"/> 
        </MenuItem>
    </m:SplitButton
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20612/A-WPF-SplitButton

the second approach is to host the `Menu` control inside the `DropDownContent` and re-style everything, there will be a lot of xaml markup.

the `Menu` control will be easy to re-style, the only thing you need to do is make sure that menu items are displayed vertically instead of horizontally, using the following markup:

```
    <Style TargetType="Menu">
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

the hardest part is styling the `MenuItems`, they are styled based on their `Role` property. It can have four possible values:

1. TopLevelHeader : direct child of `Menu` with sub-menu items.
2. TopLevelItem   : direct child of `Menu` without  sub-menu items.
3. SubmenuHeader  : direct child of `MenuItem` with sub-menu items.
4. SubmenuItem    : direct child of `MenuItem` without sub-menu items.

Regards

Comment: alrh`s CustomControl was quite helpful. I had some trouble bringing it over to my project, so I ended up just bringing it in as a dll.